# Magento 2.2.2 product images are not loading on product page

Tags: magento2.2.2, gallery-image

I am using Magento 2.2.2 in which product images loading on all other pages except product page.

[image]

After solved bootstrap error

[image]

Comment: How did you add bootstrap file? As console shows its coming from static not pub/static

Comment: I have solve that bootstrap issue. but still getting same error

Comment: Can you update the question with updated console error?

Comment: I have updated my que

Comment: Still there are issues with javasripts. Can you find those and solve it.